# How to get IMEI Number in Android 10,11,12 Programcally in My Android Application

Tags: android, android-12, android-version

How To Get IMEI Number in Android 12 java.lang.SecurityException: getSerial: The user 10034 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
If Any One has any idea about it how to over come this Problem Please Help me out.

Thanks in Advence

Comment: You can't access IMEI number above android 10. [privacy change in android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

Comment: I Read it Whole Brief Details so please can you tell How Can i get Android ID Manually in Mobile Device @Nitish Thanks for replying

Comment: How Can I get Manually Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID in Mobile Device if any one has idea please let me know

Comment: `Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

Comment: @PedroOliveira How Can i get Android ID Manually Way in Mobile Device???

Comment: @AakarshRai , is this what you are looking for? https://www.gtricks.com/android/2-ways-to-find-android-device-id-and-change-it/